# Vitals for Bishop's Crown

Tags: vegetables, chili

Someone gifted me a seedling (if that's the right term -- it's just over a handspan high) of Bishop's Crown (hot peppers).

I did some googling, but I'm not sure what the vitals of the plant are:

- Hardiness (USDA zone 4-12?)
- Type (annual? perennial?)
- The plant was purchased from a store. Should I assume it needs to be hardened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Hardiness (USDA zone 4-12?)

They  can't handle any frost. USDA hardiness zones 10b - 14 should work well. In colder climates, grow as annuals, or overwinter inside.

> - Type (annual? perennial?)

Perennial, in warm climates, or if overwintered indoors. Generally grown as an annual.

> - The plant was purchased from a store. Should I assume it needs to be hardened?

Definitely harden them off, if they aren't used to direct sun. It's easy to burn plants with sun when they've been it indirect light for a while. Also harden them to the temperature if it's regularly dropping below 45 degrees F. in your area. Also, don't fertilize after planting until the plant has rooted in.

Comment: Thanks. I'll grow it inside this year and see how it goes. That seems easier (and it becomes "perennial").